# Edit posts in Wordpress "on fly"

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote small web site on Wordpress. If admin adds new post, user should update web page to see new post. How can I add, edit, delete posts "on fly" for users without updating page?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate what you mean by "update"? Do you mean "refresh" or "reload" the page?

Comment: @DilipRajBaral
User presses "F5" to see new post. I need to add new post "on fly" without reloading the page

Answer (score 0):

This should be solvable with an plugin. After a bit of searching I found [this](https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/) plugin. It should do the trick for you.

Comment: I installed plugin, but post didn't refresh for user automatically. User should refresh page to see new post.